# Can I ask for graphic design review on this site?

Tags: discussion, design, asking-questions

Let's say I have a design I created a ui design(web/mobile/desktop) but I just feel it can be improved or the colors are not in that perfect synergy; can I post my question by asking for a design review for my design? Because I don't know of a stackexchange site created specifically for graphic design review, like e.g. what is codereview.stackexchange for stackoverflow.

So is it possible to ask for a graphic design review on this website?

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Ryan doesn't really matter but probably should dupe to the critique guidelines